# Locked posts shouldn't show up for review

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

[This post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review-beta/low-quality-posts/268) came up while using the new "Review Low Quality Posts" tool, but it wouldn't let me vote because the post is locked.  If you can't vote on it, it shouldn't pop up for review in the first place.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128475/locked-posts-appear-in-review-queues

Comment: @Dynamic If you check the [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141435/new-beta-review-displays-locked-posts) on the duplicate of the question you point to, you'll see that, although it was marked status-completed, the bug persisted on ProgSE. Don't really know if it's fixed yet or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the late response; this issue was [fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141435/new-beta-review-displays-locked-posts/143562#comment425684_143562) on Sep 25, 2012. Thanks for the report.